# Perform Button click event when user press Enter key in Textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have to perform `Button1` click event when user press `Enter key` in `Textbox1`

Comment: better to define a function that will be called on both click and press key event

Comment: If you put it in a form tag that happens automatically right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the aspx page load event, add an `onkeypress` to the box.

```
this.TextBox1.Attributes.Add(
    "onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + this.Button1.ClientID + "')");
```

Then add this javascript to evaluate the key press, and if it is "enter," click the right button.

```html
<script>
    function button_click(objTextBox,objBtnID)
    {
        if(window.event.keyCode==13)
        {
            document.getElementById(objBtnID).focus();
            document.getElementById(objBtnID).click();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Careful, as this emits a `window.event is undefined` in Firefox.

Comment: What is the fix for this? @AdrianMar

Comment: This didn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255385/how-to-prevent-the-trigger-of-another-button?noredirect=1#comment43006332_27255385

Comment: This is an ugly hack. The correct answer is the one with more upvotes.

Comment: This is not the right solution for this.  Use the DefaultButton idea listed in another answer,

Answer (score 100):

Put your form inside an asp.net panel control and set its defaultButton attribute with your button Id. See the code below:

```
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
             </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, requires .Net 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Panel also nicely converts to div, so just replaced my div with this and put proper cssclass in. Works like a charm.

Comment: Prefer this over some of the other answers, very simple.

Comment: It worked fine for me with just the panel control on it. I dont understand why you using updatepanel on the solution. does it have any specific action on the panel or just an added code. sorry i dont know much about the panel.

Comment: @Black Canery, Panel only is required. I just used the code in the question.

Comment: @Harun What if text-box is somewhere above the button I mean not together then how we could achieve the same?

Comment: Love this solution as it is very simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Codeproject has a complete solution for this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17241/Capturing-the-Enter-key-to-cause-a-button-click

and like the article says: "decide which solution best fits your needs"

=================== EDITED ANSWER ============================

The link mentioned above, talks about two ways of capturing the "Enter Key" event:

**Javascript** (bind the onKeyPress event to the object and create a javascript function to check which key was pressed and do your logic)

_Page_Load in code behind:_

```
 //Add the javascript so we know where we want the enter key press to go
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   txtboxFirstName.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", 
                   "doClick('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "',event)");
   txtboxLastName.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", 
                  "doClick('" + btnSearch.ClientID + "',event)");
}
```

*Javascript code:*

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    function doClick(buttonName,e)
    {
        //the purpose of this function is to allow the enter key to 
        //point to the correct button to click.
        var key;

         if(window.event)
              key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
         else
              key = e.which;     //firefox

        if (key == 13)
        {
            //Get the button the user wants to have clicked
            var btn = document.getElementById(buttonName);
            if (btn != null)
            { //If we find the button click it
                btn.click();
                event.keyCode = 0
            }
        }
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

**Panel Control**

```
<asp:Panel ID="panSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch2" Width="100%" >
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxFirstName2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

***Quoting:***

> Notice that the Panel tag has a property called DefaultButton. You set
>   this property to the button ID of the button you want to be clicked on
>   an Enter key press event. So any text box inside of the Panel will
>   direct its Enter key press to the button set in the DefaultButton
>   property of the Panel

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. — [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Albireo i edited the answer, hopefully this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

in the html code only, add a panel that contains the page's controls. Inside the panel, add a line DefaultButton = "buttonNameThatClicksAtEnter". See the example below, there should be nothing else required.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1"> //add this!
  //here goes all the page controls and the trigger button
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
</asp:Panel> //and this too!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript/jquery:

```
<script>
    function runScript(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#myButton").click(); //jquery
            document.getElementById("myButton").click(); //javascript
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:textbox id="txtUsername" runat="server" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" />

<asp:LinkButton id="myButton" text="Login" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

In HTML:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onKeyDown="submitButton(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

And javascript:

```
function submitButton(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $('#Button1').trigger('click');
        }
    }
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //load data and fill to gridview
} // fixed the function view for users
```

Hope this help

Comment: isn't `onKeyDown` the same as the `textChanged` event for the control? that means that the button would be clicked for every character input into the textbox, that could be bad, even if you are using an if statement to determine what key was pressed. the other solutions are better.

Answer (score -3):

use Jquery or something here is example

of it http://riderdesign.com/articles/Check-username-availability-with-JQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx
i hope i will help you more

Comment: link only answers are not safe for our site.