# Not getting Id in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

C#

```
HtmlButton btnSave = new HtmlButton();
btnSave.ID = "btnSave" + i.ToString();

btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return SubmitSave(" + btnSave.ID + ");");
```

javascript

```
function save(e)
{
     var getId=e.id;
}
```

I am not getting id in Mozilla firefox,bout its working fine in IE

Comment: Post the output html as well.

Comment: I am creating dynamic control. No Html code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Client ID` instead of the `ID` `btnSave.ClientID` as ClientID is the perfect choice to deal with such a situation.

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return SubmitSave(" + btnSave.ClientID + ");");

function save(e)
{
  var getId=e; // Now you have Client ID, you can use directly instead getting through e.id
}
```

Comment: I don't know why that's working in IE and not Mozilla, I guess it is not working in IE as well, but I can't say anything and can't test at the moment as I don't have VisualStudio at the moment. But I have mention the method in my answer, that's the right way to handle such situation.

Comment: @Jared; Have a look at this answer as well, In this answer, a similar thing is done what MayP was looking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948171/perform-button-click-event-when-user-press-enter-key-in-textbox/5948230#5948230

Comment: I hope I am able to explain you what he was looking :)

Comment: This is not the reason why it's not working, and it won't help a bit in this situation. Using ClientID is good advice, as it's intended for getting an id usable in script, but it's not the id that is the problem here, but how the id is used.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the id as a variable. Some browsers add the id:s as properties in the window object so that you can access them directly, but to make it work in anything but those few browsers you should use the getElementByID method to locate the element.

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return SubmitSave(document.getElementByID('" + btnSave.ID + "'));");
```

Comment: in his case btnSave.ID return probably btnSave1, something like. what if he is using Master page and that ID is not right one that he can find using document.GetelementByID, As ClientID is the right choice to handle such situation

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: As the code is working in IE (which is one of the browsers that adds the id:s to the window object), it's not the id that is the problem. Using ClientID is correct, but it's not the solution to this problem.