# Tracing Enter button event in textbox in asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perform Button click event when user press Enter key in Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948171/perform-button-click-event-when-user-press-enter-key-in-textbox)

I want to trace an enter button keypress event in asp.net and c#.I dont want to use javascript for it.

whenever there is Enter press in the textbox I want to call a function that takes as parameters the textbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several ways to do it:

### Using a Panel

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="but">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />
    <asp:Button Text="text1" runat="server" ID="but" OnClick="click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

### Specifying the default button in the Form tag

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="but" defaultfocus="txt">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I already have a form tag in my page,and I think I cannot use another form tag.

Comment: The attributes are applied to the **only form available in an ASP.Net page**, the `defaultbutton` only specifies which button will be executed when you press enter, the rest of your controls will work the same way

Answer (score 0):

Cannot capture/trace the keypress event in ASP.NET without JavaScript.