# Enter Key Event in ASP.NET WebForm to Perform Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net Textbox & Button in WebForm Page. When the enter key is pressed in textbox the button click should happen to load data to gridview on the page. Please suggest any sample code

Comment: _suggest any sample code_ is not a good way to ask here. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('Button1').click()"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

Comment: want to do it with asp controls

Comment: This should work <form id="Form1">
       defaultbutton="SubmitButton"
       defaultfocus="TextBox1"
       runat="server"></form>

Answer (score 8):

Wrap that form in a panel,
and make that button default button

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="button_id" runat="server">
your form here
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Excellent One     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
        Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Style="display: none" />
        
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

Comment: Very Nice and Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the same kinda question asked in the forum already....[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948171/perform-button-click-event-when-user-press-enter-key-in-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

In HTML:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onKeyDown="submitButton(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

And javascript:

```
function submitButton(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $('#Button1').trigger('click');
        }
    }
```

Code bihide:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load data and fill to gridview
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Does not work  with the above code