# How to prevent the trigger of another button

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following in my ASP.net page:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." size="30" id="pageLink" />
<br />
<span id="imgGo" class="imgGo floatRight"></span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.imgGo').click(function () {
    var strString = $("#pageLink").val()
    var strSearch = "http://www.google.com/search=";
    var url = strSearch + strString;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
});

$("#pageLink").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
        $(".imgGo").click();
    }
});
```

When I enter something in the textbox and click the `imgGo` span it works fine but if instead I hit enter, my search button which is in another panels gets triggered.

How can I either modify my JQuery code to ensure that doesn't happen or add code-behind to ensure `imgGo` is triggered only if enter button is pressed while the `pageLink` textbox has the focus?

I tried the following but didn't work because `imgGo` is not a button:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMedSearch" runat="server" DefaultButton="GoImg">
    <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." size="30" id="p2" />-->
    <asp:TextBox Width="30" ID="pageLink" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <!--<span id="imgGo" class="imgGo floatRight"></span>-->
    <asp:Label ID="imgGo" CssClass="imgGo floatRight" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I get the following error:

```
The DefaultButton of 'pnlMedSearch' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.
```

I would like to use the textbox which is not a ASP.net control because the `placeholder` attribute is important in my case.

Comment: Does the search button in the other panel have the `imgGo` class? I noticed that you're targetting `.imgGo` through jQuery. This will fire the events for any matched elements, you probably want to do this based on a unique `id` instead.

Comment: `imgGo` is only used for this instance only.

Comment: Your error message is a bit odd `The DefaultButton of 'pnlMedSearch' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.`.. Are you trying to use a label as the default button? In your example HTML you've set the default button as `GoImg`, so why not just add an `<asp:Button>` to the panel with an ID of `GoImg`? That should work...

Comment: I need to use `placeholder` for the textbox which I can't in ASP.net

Comment: You can absolutely use a `placeholder=""` attribute on an `<asp:TextBox />`. For example `<asp:TextBox Width="30" ID="pageLink" runat="server" placeholder="Foo" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept the same HTML content and modified my Jquery to the following:

```
$("#medlineSearch").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $("#imgGo").click();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Adding the `return false;` ensure it didn't invoke anything else on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate version for the same.

Register as an event on any tags:

```
 onkeydown="pressButtonOnEnter('IdOfMyButton', event);"
```

Into your .js file:

```
function pressButtonOnEnter(buttonId, event) {
    var key = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (key == 13) {
        $("#" + buttonId).click();
    }
}
```

It works in asp.net as well.You can simply add it to an asp:textbox for instance.